# Unkonwn mutation type in vuex

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex, mutation

I tried to mutate the state in vuex but, it always says `vuex.esm-browser.js?5502:976 [vuex] unknown mutation type: addToCart`. I called addToCart in mutation in two different ways as follows, but it is not working. It always throws the same error.

```
<button @click="addToCart(product)" class="add">Add</button>
```

```
import {mapMutations} from 'vuex'
    export default{
        methods:{
            ...mapMutations(["addToCart"]),
        },
        props: ["product"],
    }
</script>
```

```
Vuex store
```

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
    state:{
        cart: []
    },
    mutation:{
        addToCart(state, product){
            let item = state.cart.find(i=>i.id === product.id)

            if(item){
                item.quantity++
            }else{
                state.cart.push({...product, quantity: 1})
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```
I even tried this also
```

```
<button @click="addToCart()" class="add">Add</button>

<script>
   props: ["product"],
   methods:{
        addToCart(){
        this.$store.commit('addToCart', this.product)
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: it's "mutations" not "mutation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be: `mutations` and not `mutation` in the store file?